# VBA Excel-Sending mail from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have following lines of code to send mail under command button click event.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cdoConfig
Dim msgOne

Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
With cdoConfig.Fields
    .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    .Item(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 557  
    .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.emailsr.com" 'SMTP server goes here
    '.Item(cdoSendUserName) = "My Username"
    '.Item(cdoSendPassword) = "myPassword"
    .Update
End With

Set msgOne = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set msgOne.Configuration = cdoConfig
msgOne.To = "adbc@adbc.com"
msgOne.from = "bcda@adbc.com"
msgOne.Subject = "Test CDO"
msgOne.TextBody = "It works just fine."
msgOne.Send
End Sub
```

When i execute this i am facing an error like **RunTime Error-2147220977(8004020f): Automation Error The event class for this subscription is in an invalid partition**

```
msgOne.Send
```

The above line is giving the error during execution.
So i moved on to CDO approach for sending an email.Now i am executing following code.

```
Dim iMsg As Object
Dim iConf As Object
Dim strbody As String
    Dim Flds As Variant

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields
    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mysmtpserver.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "mymailId"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "Mypassword"
        .Update

    End With

strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 4"

With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = "tomailid"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .From = "mymailid"
    .Subject = "New"
    .TextBody = strbody
    .Send
End With
```

But **Send** is giving me an error like **Run-time error -2147220977(8004020f): The server rejected one or more recipient addresses. The server response was: 554 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: Access denied** And some times it is like **Runtime Error-'2147220975(80040211)Automation error**

Comment: See if this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007270/asp-mail-error-the-event-class-for-this-subscription-is-in-an-invalid-partition

Comment: i tried with that code it is also giving same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are using would work in VBScript or other similar languages if you registered the CDO Type Library. The type library contains the properties `cdoSendUsingMethod` etc so that you don't have to use the full urn. In VBA, you have to use the full urn. Ron De Bruin has a good reference about this at http://www.rondebruin.nl/cdo.htm.

From his site you can see the difference between your code and that required for VBA, specifically here:

```
     Set Flds = iConf.Fields
        With Flds
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") _
                           = "Fill in your SMTP server here"
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
            .Update
        End With
```

Comment: yeah i visited that site, eventhough i use that code it is giving me same error. Whichever code i use i am getting same error..!

Comment: Hi Nick Pekins, with some edits i executed the code with proposed changes now i am getting some diffrent error like **Run-time error -2147220977(8004020f):
   The server rejected one or more recipient addresses. The server 
response was: 554 5.7.1 <test@delloitte.co.in>: Sender address rejected: Access denied
**

Comment: @SaiKiranMandhala Well that's actually good. It means that you have connected to your mail server and the server rejected the sender address that you supplied. I know that doesn't sound good, but it means your code works but you need to set up the sender address on your mail server (or use login credentials).

Comment: yeah i hard coded the login credentials. But i couldn't resolve that error:-(

Comment: @SaiKiranMandhala You can't use `.Item(cdoSendUserName)` and `.Item(cdoSendPassword)` just like the other ones as mentioned in my answer. You will need to visit the link I gave you for the right urn

Comment: yeah i used these lines <br> .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "mailid"
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "enterpassword"<br> still i am getting error:-( And the error is RunTime Error-2147220977(8004020f): Automation Error The event class for this subscription is in an invalid partition. Only the .Send statement giving me error.

Comment: Atlast i completed this task..Thanks a lot Nick.

Comment: @SaiKiranMandhala Can you please share your findings and how you achieved this task.